# Is it possible to make form collection with generic forms? Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

So i am making a excercises for something so i have a huge form (10 exercises) with collection of smaller forms (the little exercises). My problem is that the exercise can be anything, it can be one TextType or one password field or even 10 numeric fields, you get the point. Everywhere i saw the collection type to have entry_type of some data and it is always the same.. I want something generic.
Sorry if this was asked before and thanks <3

It is currently working when i use one type. example:

```
class MultipleExercisesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('exercises', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' =>  ActivePassiveType::class,
                'label' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            
        ]);
    }
}

class ActivePassiveType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('activePassive', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Aktiva' => true,
                    'Pasiva' => false,
                ],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'label' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CollectionType is mainly for relations like OneToMany in your database etc. But i think i know what you're trying to achieve.

You can combine multiple form types like this, so you can have as many unique forms as you like in one master form...

**Your main form type:**

```
...
use App\Form\ExerciseOneFormType;
use App\Form\ExerciseTwoFormType;

class MultipleExercisesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('exerciseOne', ExerciseOneFormType::class)
            ->add('exerciseTwo', ExerciseTwoFormType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Submit'
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

**ExerciseOneFormType:**

```
class ExerciseOneFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('test1', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ExerciseOne Checkbox',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('test2', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ExerciseOne Text Box',
            ))
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => YourEntity::class //or null
        ));
    }
}
```

**ExerciseTwoFormType:**

```
class ExerciseTwoFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('anotherTest1', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ExerciseTwo Text Box',
            ))
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => YourEntity::class //or null
        ));
    }
}
```

**Your controller:**

```
...
use App\Form\MultipleExercisesType;
...

#[Route('/exercises', name: 'exercises')]
public function Exercises(Request $request): Response
{
    $exercisesForm = $this->createForm(MultipleExercisesType::class, null, array());

    $exercisesForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($exercisesForm->isSubmitted() && $exercisesForm->isValid()) {
        ....
    }

    return $this->render('exercises.html.twig', array(
        'exercises_form' => $exercisesForm->createView()
    ));
}

// Render the form in your twig file using form(exercises_form) or however you would like too.
```

Obviously this is just a small example from the information you have given. Not sure if you're using any data_type to get and set data in any entities etc.